# Use rsync with nc as transport layer

Tags: ssh, rsync, netcat

By default, rsync uses ssh as a transport layer. Unfortunately with fast local network, ssh is very slow. Is it possible use rsync with netcat / nc ?

I have make some experiments, but it does not work for me. I want eliminate ssh, because it is bottelneck.

Of course, I want use it with Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example using the debian/ubuntu version of nc (using named pipe as described in [nc(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/netcat-openbsd/nc.1.en.html#CLIENT/SERVER_MODEL) because nc doesn’t have `-e` or `-c`)

On the server side:

```sh
rm -f /tmp/rsyncpipe && mkfifo /tmp/rsyncpipe && cat /tmp/rsyncpipe | (read cmd && eval "$cmd") | nc -l 1243 >/tmp/rsyncpipe
```

On the client side:

```sh
rsync --progress --rsh='bash -c "(echo ""$@""; cat) | nc $0 1243"' <file> 10.142.0.119:<file>
```

Unfortunately, due to the fifo, `rsync` stays open even after the transfer is complete, so you have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on both sides when it looks like it’s done (when `--progress` reports `to-check=0/n`).

Answer (score 1):

I think that will not work, because rsync need access to the destination filesystem.
But, what about using an alternate shell using `--rsh` operator or using rsync in `daemon mode`?